# Enabling DMA in pc with windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, performance, 3dmark

I was checking my PC settings using AIDA64 (supposed to be the successor for Everest - it basically shows you detailed hardware you currently have). For my ATA hard disk it shows the setting for DMA as "supported, disabled". But when I checked the windows setting I see that it is actually enabled. How can I find out which is correct? And if its disabled what do I do to enable it? Thanks for your help.

**Edit:** If you right-click on the screenshot - open in new window/save and then open it you can see a much bigger version. Please let me know if you have any problems seeing it.

Here are some screenshots for this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the following information [here](http://windows7themes.net/how-to-enable-dma-in-windows-7.html). If you go to enable it, you will also be able to check if it is enabled.

-Hope this helps.

> 1. Open the explorer (STRG+E)
> 2. Right-click on “Computer” and click on “Manage”
> 3. Click on “Device Manager”
> 4. Uncollapse IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers
> 5. Right-click on any label where “Channel” is part of the name – Click
>      on Properties
> 6. Go to the Advanced Settings tab, under Device Properties check “Enable
>      DMA”

Comment: If this doesn't work - uninstall the adapter drivers and let Windows reinstall them. Windows disables DMA if it encounters x errors in a row, but these checkboxes remain checked

Comment: How do we check the errors encountered?

Comment: Thanks for your steps. I had already read these steps and at step 6 noticed that "Enable DMA" is already checked. Hence the confusion.

Comment: @Mugen wow, I feel stupid now. I didn't notice that they were your screenshots. Sorry for telling you information that you already knew. I would have to agree with @Sathya on this one then. Uninstall the drivers and reinstall. I don't know if there is a way to see errors unless they were recent enough. You may be able to find the errors in event viewer. I think that the simplest way to get to event viewer is to click "start" button and type event viewer and let Windows 7 find it for you. Also, did you try disabling DMA and re-enabling it? If you need anymore help, please let me know.

Comment: Thats okay, it happens to us all. :) Thanks for trying.